# RSpec how to exception of raising error - expected ZeroDivisionError but nothing was raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to check if number divided by 0 will rise `ZeroDivisionError` from below method

```
def progress_percent
  (activity_reads.size / journey.cms_activity_ids.size.to_f)
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  0
end
```

My specs are:

```
context 'when journey does not have activity' do
  let!(:activity_read) { ['test', 'test'] }
  let(:journey) { build(:journey, :without_activity) }

  it 'raise the ZeroDivisionError' do
    expect { call }.to raise_error(ZeroDivisionError)
  end
end
```

When I put `binding.pry` to progress_percent method I'm getting what I was expected so `activity_read = 2` and `journey.cms_activity_ids.size.to_f = 0` but in my test I've got an error:

```
 Failure/Error: expect { call }.to raise_error(ZeroDivisionError)
   expected ZeroDivisionError but nothing was raised
```

EDIT:

It's a part of bigger class

```
def call
  Progres.update(
    user_id: current_user.id,
    percent_progress: progress_percent,
  )
end

private

def progress_percent
  (activity_reads.size / journey.cms_activity_ids.size.to_f)
rescue ZeroDivisionError
  0
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not an early return instead?:

```
def progress_percent
  return 0 unless journey.cms_activity_ids.size > 0

  activity_reads.size / journey.cms_activity_ids.size
end
```

also, you don't need to cast to float or integer, the "assoc_ids" AR method will return an object that responds to `:size`

Answer (score 1):

As Spickermann says, if you're handling the error, you don't test for it.

What you should do is confirm that the method returns `0` in that scenario.

Having said that... you are converting `journey.cms_activity_ids.size` to a float so that won't raise an error anyway. Dividing by 0.0 will give a result of `Infinity` instead of raising an error.

You can test for infinity with...

```
expect(subject.send(:progress_percent)).to eq BigDecimal('Infinity')
```

If the non-zero numerator is negative, and the denominator is zero, you'll get negative infinity. Test for that with...

```
expect(subject.send(:progress_percent)).to eq BigDecimal('-Infinity')
```

Note, however, that if you have a "negative zero", it's slightly different: `-1.0 / -0.0` returns Infinity, not negative Infinity.

If the numerator and denominator are both zero and at least one is a float, you will get `NaN` returned.  Test for that with...

```
expect(subject.send(:progress_percent).nan?).to be true
```

`NaN` never equals anything, not even another `NaN`

Comment: And at the end it gives me `Infinity` or NaN - how to write a test to show such a result?

Comment: Edited my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not raised by `call`, because you catch/rescue it.

```
expect(call).to eq(0)
```

Should pass.